# Having an issue with the launcher icon of my app on Android in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, icons, size

I'm having an annoying issue with the `launcher icon` of my app. It seems to be too small. So, it is definitely smaller than all the other icons on my phone.

So, I just created my icon with a size of 512x512 pixels. Then in Eclipse, in my project, I chose `New > Android Icon Set`, then I clicked `next` and then I clicked on `Image` to choose my icon. After, I set a tick in the checkbox called `"Trim Surrounding Blank Space"`. `"Additional Padding"` have I set to 5%, `"Foreground Scaling"` to `"Center"` and the `Shape` to `"None"`. Then I clicked on `finish`. Eclipse created then the icons to all the correct sizes (48x48 in mdpi, 72x72 in hdpi and so on). Then I let my project run on my ADV and after I installed in on my phone. But the icon was just too small.
I have also gooled after some solutions and found `"Android Asset Studio"` which is a web application to generate icons.

Android Asset Studio: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

I clicked on `"Launcher icons"` and did the same steps as I did in Eclipse. But unfortunately without any avail. So, I installed my app with new icon on my phone. The result, the icon was still too small.

I also had a look at similar questions here but no answer has sloved my issue.

Maybe you can help me, please?

I'm looking forward to your help!

If you need any more information, just tell me because I have no Idea where the issue could be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to read this reference [page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).
Then, in each drawable folder put te corresponding icon, at the proper resoution in dpi.

Unfortunately, Eclipse itself and the Asset Studio produce ion at 72 dpi for each size!!
This will produce weird results

Please note that dpi measures the RESOLUTION, not the SIZE of an image.

```
resolution != size;
```

dp (or dip) relate to dpi, of course, but are a different beast.
They serve the purpose of scaling pixels according to the correct dpi resolution.

Now, your mdpi graphics SHOULD REALLY BE SAVED AT 160 dpi, not 72 dpi.
And ldpi at 120 dpi, and hdpi at 240 dpi... and so on.
72 dpi really don't suffice - not for my tastes.

Comment: Well, I already did what is written on that page. And I also put the correct icons with the correct pixel size/dp in the correct folders. And my icon is still to small. But what do you mean with that Eclipse and Android Asset Studio pruduce icons at 72 dpi? With those both tools I got the different sizes of my icon, so they aren't same sized. Or do I misunderstand something and there is a difference between "dp" and "dpi"?

Comment: You misunderstood. dpi is the measure for RESOLUTION, not SIZE. dp (or dip) relate to dpi, of course, but are a different beast. They serve the purpose of scaling pixels according to the correct dpi resolution. Now, your mdpi graphics SHOULD REALLY BE SAVED AT 160 dpi, not 72 dpi. and ldpi at 120 dpi, and hdpi at 240 dpi... and so on. So 72 dpi really don't suffice - not for my tastes.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't answer so long. Anyway I understand now, what did you mean and also the difference between the resolution and the size. I thank you a lot for your help! So, I have  tried exactly what you have suggested me but it unfortunatel didn't work. My Icons got an ugly, bold, black, outline and got blurred.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong... can you show the icons you WANT (not those you GOT)? Remember that you should not scale UP, but scale DOWN (so start form a big image and then scale it down in your graphic editor - normally, if you scale the dpis, the pixels will accomodate to a well poportioned scale)

Comment: Oh! That seems to be my mistake... I know that I have to scale down images but I didn't do that with the dpi of my icons! I scaled them up from low dpi to high dpi! God, I'm so...! Anyway, I use Paint.NET as my graphic editor, so I'll have a look at its save options if I could save my icon at a high dpi to scale them down after. Thank you a lot again, I will try it out and hope that it will work this time!

Comment: If you do things mindfully, you'll get your results.

Answer (score 0):

I found when I created:

1. the image resolutions at 160px - 640px resolution
2. change the "print size" (I'm using Gimp) to the 48px - 192px respectfully (while leaving the resolution intact)
3. import all those different files into all my appropriately sized drawables folders
4. change the Android Manifest to an ic_launcher_name_xxhdpi (my folders didn't have xxxhdpi)...

then it automatically takes the right size you need, even though they are all different files in there with different names and different sizes. Score!

Specifications are in [Android Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).